# What is the BigQuery equivalent of PostgreSQL's `DISTINCT ON`?

Tags: google-bigquery, distinct, window-functions, distinct-on

I am migrating some queries from PostgreSQL dialect over to BigQuery. One nice pattern in [PostgreSQL is `DISTINCT ON (key)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT), which returns the first row for every key based on the sequence as defined in the `ORDER BY` section.

Is there a similar pattern I can use in BigQuery that would avoid wrapping the query as a CTE?

PostgreSQL query:

```sql
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON (user_id)
    user_id,
    updated_on,
    net_change
FROM
    table_name
ORDER BY
    user_id, updated_on DESC
```

Answer (score 8):

The BigQuery equivalent of the PostgreSQL dialect's `DISTINCT ON (key)` is [the `QUALIFY` clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause) with a window function:

```sql
SELECT
    user_id,
    updated_on,
    net_change
FROM
    table_name
QUALIFY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY updated_on DESC) = 1
```